# Strange package name after desugaring

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I use Android Studio 4.0 with `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true`

When I use `LocalDateTime` I see `j$.time.LocalDateTime` instead of `java.time.LocalDateTime`. Why is that?

example

```
val kClass = LocalDateTime::class
Log.d("TestApp","class: $kClass")
```

Comment: Probably to not collide with the real `LocalDateTime` implementation on Android 8.0+. The desugared stuff has to call some implementation, supplied by some library, for older devices. If they called that library's classes `java.time.LocalDateTime` and kin, then there would be compile problems with a `compileSdkVersion` of 26 or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for desugaring to work, the fully-qualified class name needs to be different than the "normal" one.  If it weren't, then on newer versions of Android where that class exists, there would be two classes with the same name, and that can lead to unpredictable issues.

Thus, D8 replaces `java` with `j$`, a package name that cannot be expressed in Java, so it won't conflict with any classes you may have defined yourself.

For more information on how D8's desugar backports types like LocalDateTime, see this excellent [blog post](https://jakewharton.com/d8-library-desugaring/#backporting-types) from Jake Wharton.